# Multiplication of two huge dense matrices Hadamard-multiplied by a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, lapack

I have two dense matrices `A` and `B`, and each of them has a size fo `3e5x100`. Another sparse binary matrix, `C`, with size `3e5x3e5`. I want to find the following quantity: `C ∘ (AB')`, where `∘` is Hadamard product (i.e., element wise) and `B'` is the transpose of `B`. Explicitly calculating `AB'` will ask for crazy amount of memory (~500GB). Since the end result won't need the whole `AB'`, it is sufficient to only calculate the multiplication `A_iB_j'` where `C_ij != 0`, where `A_i` is the column `i` of matrix `A` and `C_ij` is the element at location `(i,j)` of the matrix `C`. A suggested approach would be like the algorithm below:

```py
result = numpy.initalize_sparse_matrix(shape = C.shape)
while True:
 (i,j) = C_ij.pop_nonzero_index() #prototype function returns the nonzero index and then points to the next nonzero index
 if (i,j) is empty:
   break
 result(i,j) = A_iB_j'
```

This algorithm however takes too much time. Is there anyway to improve it using `LAPACK/BLAS` algorithms? I  am coding in Python so I think `numpy` can be more human friendly wrapper for `LAPACK/BLAS`.

Comment: how sparse is your C? how long does it take to grab all coordinates of the 1's in C? I don't recall any algorithm can reduce this computation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this computation using the following, assuming `C` is stored as a [`scipy.sparse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) matrix:

```python
C = C.tocoo()
result_data = C.data * (A[C.row] * B[C.col]).sum(1)
result = sparse.coo_matrix((result_data, (row, col)), shape=C.shape)
```

Here we show that the result matches the naive algorithm for some smaller inputs:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

N = 300
M = 10

def make_C(N, nnz=1000):
  data = np.random.rand(nnz)
  row = np.random.randint(0, N, nnz)
  col = np.random.randint(0, N, nnz)
  return sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(N, N))


A = np.random.rand(N, M)
B = np.random.rand(N, M)
C = make_C(N)

def f_naive(C, A, B):
  return C.multiply(np.dot(A, B.T))

def f_efficient(C, A, B):
  C = C.tocoo()
  result_data = C.data * (A[C.row] * B[C.col]).sum(1)
  return sparse.coo_matrix((result_data, (C.row, C.col)), shape=C.shape)

np.allclose(
    f_naive(C, A, B).toarray(),
    f_efficient(C, A, B).toarray()
)
# True
```

And here we see that it works for the full input size:

```python
N = 300000
M = 100

A = np.random.rand(N, M)
B = np.random.rand(N, M)
C = make_C(N)

out = f_efficient(C, A, B)

print(out.shape)
# (300000, 300000)

print(out.nnz)
# 1000
```